# Downsizing a Densenet121 under Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I have a VGG like net that performs well but takes forever to train ( ~30h) over 600 epochs
[image]

I tried to switch to keras.applications.densenet.Densenet121 for performance and quicker training time, but it clearly is overfitting even with high dropout in the dense layers.

```
    from keras.applications.densenet import DenseNet201, DenseNet121

    input_image = Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = BatchNormalization()(input_image)

    base_model = DenseNet121(
            include_top=False,
            weights='imagenet' if weights else None,
            input_shape=input_shape,
            pooling='max')

    x = base_model(x)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(128, activation='relu', name='fc2')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Dropout(0.9, name='dropout_fc2')(x)
    predictions = Dense(nb_classes, activation="softmax", name="predictions")(x)
```

[image]

Still, I want to test this kind of architecture.

If I go the `keras.applications.densenet.DenseNet121`'s implementation, I have :

```
    def DenseNet121(include_top=True,
                weights='imagenet',
                input_tensor=None,
                input_shape=None,
                pooling=None,
                classes=1000):
    return DenseNet([6, 12, 24, 16],
                    include_top, weights,
                    input_tensor, input_shape,
                   pooling, classes)
```

with `[6, 12, 24, 16]` as the layers size.

Respectively :

```
DenseNet201 = [6, 12, 48, 32]
DenseNet169 = [6, 12, 32, 32]
DenseNet121 = [6, 12, 24, 16]
```

Reference implementation are :

- [Torch DenseNets] (https://github.com/liuzhuang13/DenseNet/blob/master/models/densenet.lua)
- [TensorNets] (https://github.com/taehoonlee/tensornets/blob/master/tensornets/densenets.py)

But they use as parameters depth and growth : `-depth 100 -growthRate 12` and I cannot figure the relation between **depth/growthrate** and **layers**.

How can I downsize this model, under Keras, to have the equivalent of a `DenseNet40` for example ?

Comment: HI, I am going through similar issues now. Did you find a way to make your own Densenet40 ?

Comment: No, I modified the keras layers directly in the code in multiple ways without success. So I ended doing classic fine tuning. I did not manage to find in the papers a comprehensive description of the depth/growth/layers

Comment: Ok thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 4):

Standard implementation like DenseNet121, DenseNet169, DenseNet201, DenseNet264, uses explicit number of layers per Dense Blocks. Number of dense blacks in all of the previously mentioned network is 4 and the growth rate is 32. But the layers in them varies as follows:

```
DenseNet121 = [6, 12, 24, 16]
DenseNet169 = [6, 12, 32, 32]
DenseNet201 = [6, 12, 48, 32]
DenseNet264 = [6, 12, 64, 48]
```

For implementation with custom number of layers and growth rate you can either come up with your own number of layer per dense block or uniformly distribute the number of layer per dense block.

The number of layers in DenseNet is of form `3 N + 4`. And you can use your own growth rate in the custom network. (ex. 12).

If you want to use keras implementation to make custom nets, you'll have to pass it a list of layer per block.
So if you want a 100 layer network, pass a `[25, 25, 25, 25]` list.

```
DenseNet([25, 25, 25, 25],
         include_top, weights,
         input_tensor, input_shape,
         pooling, classes)
```

Note that keras currently only supports DenseNets with 4 blocks, so if you are modifying keras implementation of DenseNet you have to pass it a list of size 4.

And change the hardcoded growth rate in the [following line](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/8ad32411a065d67262f76473b8508bb2ce3a2fa6/keras_applications/densenet.py#L68) in `keras-applications/keras_applications/densenet.py`.
Just change:

```
x = conv_block(x, 32, name=name + '_block' + str(i + 1))
```

to:

```
x = conv_block(x, your_growth_rate, name=name + '_block' + str(i + 1))
```